# Configure Multiple Data soureces in Logstash configuration files?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to load two different configurations at a time in Logstash Pipeline. Those two configurations have different Input, Filters, and Output.

Note: My ELK setup on Docker Swarm

I tried like below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-9-9-92 logstash]$ ls -lrth pipeline/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 1.4K Feb 20 16:53 alb.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 2.0K Feb 20 17:28 logstash.conf
```

@Here my Elasticsearch is same but indexes are different in those files. Please help me with it.

Comment: are you running logstash using the command line or as a service?

Comment: I'm running my Logstash as a Docker container

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use de -f flag for different inputs:

Edit with thanks to @leandrojmp:

```
logstash -f '/path/{file1,file2}'
```

Or use a single file with if conditions for the filter and output plugins - if you have the same input.

Comment: passing multiple `-f` flags does not work, it needs to be `logstash -f '/path/{file1,file2}'`, which will concatenate the files and run as a single pipeline.